# Why are Ruby's file related types string-based (stringly typed)?

Tags: ruby, strong-typing

e.g. `Dir.entries` returns an array of strings vs an array containing `File` or `Dir` instances.
Most methods on Dir and File types. The instances are aneamic in comparison.

There is no `Dir#folders` or `Dir#files` - instead I explicitly

1. loop over `Dir.entries`
2. build the path (`File.expand_path`) for
   each item
3. check `File.directory?`

Simple use-cases like get all .svg **files** in this directory seem to require a number of hoops/loops/checks. Am I using Ruby wrong or does this facet of Ruby seem very un-ruby-ish?

Comment: Well, that's a fine line. Suppose, `Dir.entries` returned File objects. What if you needed just the names and rightfully thought that constructing File objects was a waste of CPU and memory?

Comment: API that you think of, it might be not in the stdlib, but there's surely a gem for it.

Comment: "There is no Dir#folders or Dir#files" - very often the underlying filesystem doesn't have that distinction (no separate lists for files and directories). So to find only the directories, stdlib method would have to do that loop you describe, only implicitly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - yes e.g. Dir.entries could return strings + Dir#entries returns typed objects. Let the consumer make the choice. A _stdlib_ method in Ruby would have the advantages of being implemented in the most performant way + make the client code shorter/read better.

Comment: @Gishu: "Dir.entries could return strings + Dir#entries returns typed objects" - as of now, I don't see the reason/logic for this. If it were the case, it'd surprise me greatly.

Comment: also see @eric's answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - well we could debate on what the methods could be called.. maybe different names are more intuitive. _typedObj.items_ yields more typed objects. e.g. Pathname.children below yielded more Pathnames (not strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs, [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) or [`Dir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html) might do just fine.

When you need to chain commands and (rightfully) think it feels un-ruby-ish to only use class methods with string parameters, you can use [`Pathname`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). It is a standard library.

## Examples

#### Dirs and Files

```
require 'pathname'

my_folder = Pathname.new('./')
dirs, files = my_folder.children.partition(&:directory?)
# dirs is now an Array of Pathnames pointing to subdirectories of my_folder
# files is now an Array of Pathnames pointing to files inside my_folder
```

#### All .svg files

If for some reason there might be folders with `.svg` extension, you can just filter the pathnames returned by `Pathname.glob` :

```
svg_files = Pathname.glob("folder/", "*.svg").select(&:file?)
```

If you want a specific syntax :

```
class Pathname
  def files
    children.select(&:file?)
  end
end

aDir = Pathname.new('folder/')
p aDir.files.find_all{ |f| f.extname == '.svg' }
```

#### Iterating the Directory tree

[`Pathname#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-find) will help.

Comment: +1 - although this is more mental baggage - learning another type ( I just refreshed the Dir and File types :) and it's interface. Readability also suffers a bit IMHO - i was writing a recursive routine that traverses the file system. But this works - has most of what I need.. for now.

Comment: Well, if you're not happy with Dir or File, learning a 3rd class isn't so bad. Pathname has many instance methods, and will make your job easier. Just curious : where does readability suffer?

Comment: As a newbie, I would first search for Dir*/File* types and try to program against them. So in a alternate reality, I'd find this more readable `aDir.files.find_all{ |f| f.extName() == '.svg' }` -- anyways no biggie. Just violated my notion of Ruby's [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: Example updated with just your syntax. Directly from Matz : http://www.artima.com/intv/ruby4.html "I was surprised by this feature of the language, so therefore Ruby violates the principle of least surprise." Wait. Wait. The principle of least surprise is not for you only. The principle of least surprise means principle of least my surprise.

Comment: @Gishu: "this is more mental baggage - learning another type" – Well, a path is not a file; the name of a thing is not the thing itself, so it *needs* to be a separate type.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - the baggage i was referring to was that i have to know to use a third class Pathname for behavior that I would expect to be in the File or Dir class. That's kinda hard to guess. Now that I know it, I ended up writing my whole recursive-descent script with just Pathname - which seems to be a mashup of path related functionality + Dir/File concerns like traversal. Indeed many of it's methods delegate to File types.

Answer (score 1):

Until you open the file it is just a path (string).

To open all .svg files

```
svgs = Dir.glob(File.join('/path/to/dir', '*.svg'))
```

On windows case doesn't matter in file paths, but in all unixoid systems (Linux, MacOS...) `file.svg` is different from `file.SVG`

To get all `.svg` files and`.SVG` files you need File::FNM_CASEFOLD flag.
If you want to get `.svg` files recursively, you need `**/*.svg`

```
svgs = Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/**/*.svg', File::FNM_CASEFOLD)
```

If you expect directories ending in`.svg` then filter them  out

```
svgs.reject! { |path| File.directory?(path) }
```